# Remove redundancy from model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have to model the concept of stores and malls. A store may or may not be contained within a mall. If a store is contained within a mall, it should share the same address/GeoMarket attributes as the parent mall. However, I also need to save the 'store number' of the store within Address_Line1 (or otherwise) but the other attributes would remain the same.

```
public class Store
{
    public int StoreId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Address_Line1 { get; set; }

    public string Address_Line2 { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Zipcode { get; set; }

    public virtual GeoMarket Market { get; set; }

    public virtual Mall Mall { get;set; }
}

public class Mall
{

    public int MallId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Address_Line1 { get; set; }

    public string Address_Line2 { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Zipcode { get; set; }

    public virtual GeoMarket Market { get; set; }

}
```

How can I best structure this so I don't save the address of the mall again in the store object?

Comment: What about a class `Address`?

Comment: Does this have a DB backing it, or are you just keeping this in memory?

Comment: Yes, DB backing. MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Store
{
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? MallId { get; set; }
    public virtual GeoMarket Market { get; set; }
    public virtual Mall Mall { get; set; }
}

class StandAloneStore : Store
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

class Address
{
    public string Address_Line1 { get; set; }

    public string Address_Line2 { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
}

class Mall
{
    public int MallId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public virtual GeoMarket Market { get; set; }

    IList<Store> Stores { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for Stores that are not inside of malls (`Mall` would be null and `MallId` would need to be `int?` and also null)

Comment: I also need to have a string for the store number if it's contained within a mall. I.e. I need another address line 1 or even an address line 3 to keep track of the store number.

Comment: updated answer. I'm not sure you need store number, as each store will already have a unique id

Comment: Why not make `Store` abstract (with an abstract `Address` property) and derive `StandAloneStore` and `InMallStore` from it?

Comment: @matt-dot-net - store number is not an identifier, it's an additional address attribute. When you go to a mall, a store has a number like a house number. I.e. Shop 16. So it's not something I want to save on the address of the mall because a mall may have many stores.